# Powershell timeout when sending email

Tags: email, powershell, smtp, smtpclient

I am trying to send a mail using powershell by making use of gmail smtp server. Here's my code snippet.

```
$sender = "user1@domain.com"
$recipient = "user2@domain.com"
$subject = "test"
$body = "test text"
$username = "user1@domain.com"
$password = "password"

$sc = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
$sc.EnableSsl = $true;
$cred = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password);
$sc.Credentials = $cred;
$emsg = new-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($sender, $recipient, $subject, $body);
$sc.Timeout = 180000
$sc.Send($emsg);
```

Everytime I recieve a timeout, even if I have fixed the timeout value to 3 minutes(180 seconds). To be more precise, the error is

```
Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "The operation has timed out."
At line:15 char:1
+ $sc.Send($emsg);
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
```

Have anyone experienced this issue before? Any suggestions or ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: The code above isn't really Powershell you are using .net classes, Powershell has send-mailmessage http://ss64.com/ps/send-mailmessage.html try that - it may not help but thought I would point out the Powershell way of doing this.

Comment: Timeouts usually mean there is a network related issue. Try pinging, or connecting through telnet or another smtp client to the same host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting that it could save someone's time too..

```
$param = @{
SmtpServer = 'smtp.gmail.com'
Port = 587
UseSsl = $true
Credential  = 'user1@domain.com'
From = 'user1@domain.com'
To = 'user2@domain.com'
Subject = 'test'
Body = "testtext"
}
Send-MailMessage @param
```

PS [here](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/10/25/pstip-sending-emails-using-your-gmail-account/).

Comment: Strange thing, sending with Thunderbird email client works with port 467 for me.  Powershell hangs with that port. And works with port 587. (the smtp server is not gmail)